# FFmpeg psycho-visual options - psy-rdoq

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to encoding and I like to do my encodings in x265 10bit. Currently, I'm facing a little issue with ffmpeg. I noticed when I'm using libx265 encoder output file looks a little bit blurred or small detail loss. Code I used to do my encodes is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:a copy -y output-x26510bit.mkv
```

I've found out psycho-visual options might help in this case. I modified my code in to

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -psy-rd 2 -psy-rdoq 4 --rdoq-level 1 -c:a copy -y output-x26510bit.mkv
```

When I issue the above command, I get an error code

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop\1>ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -psy-rd 2 -psy-rdoq
 4 -rdoq-level 1 -c:a copy -y output-x26510bit.mkv
ffmpeg version git-2020-04-03-52523b6 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enabl
e-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enabl
e-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --
enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-l
ibvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom
--enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --en
able-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 77.101 / 58. 77.101
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Unrecognized option 'psy-rdoq'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

How do I solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not valid standalone options for libx265 in `ffmpeg`. You can see what private options are supported with `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265`.

If you want to use additional options you have to use them with the `-x265-params` option:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -x265-params psy-rd=2:psy-rdoq=4:rdoq-level=1 -c:a copy output-x26510bit.mkv
```